# How to prove $\pi^3<3^\pi$ without using explicit value of $\pi$?

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory

How to prove  $\pi^3<3^\pi$ without using explicit value of $\pi$?  In the following link I proposed similar problem and got extremely amazing explanations which uses pure geometrical ideas : [How to prove: $2^\frac{3}{2}<\pi$ without writing the explicit values of $\sqrt{2}$ and $\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2111285/how-to-prove-2-frac32-pi-without-writing-the-explicit-values-of-sqrt)

Here too I am thinking some similar kind of idea (not involving calculus) but not getting any. Can there also be something like that?

Comment: Wait, should I use pre-calculus methods?

Comment: $f(x)=x^{1/x}$ is increasing when $x\in(0;e]$, decreasing when $x\in [e;+\infty)$. Since $e<3<\pi$, we get the result.

Answer (score 4):

Take the logarithm. Divide each side by $3 \pi$. Notice the question becomes:

$$ \frac{\ln \pi}{\pi} < \frac{ \ln 3}{3}$$

However, the derivative of $ f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$ is $$f'(x)=\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}$$
From the product rule. So the fucntion $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$ is decreasing if $x>e$ as $f'(x)<0$. The result follows as. $$\pi >3>e$$As seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166310/proving-mathrm-e-3), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489606/how-can-one-prove-that-e-pi) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688214/what-would-be-an-elementary-way-to-prove-that-3-pi4).

Comment: And well, that is a lot of links!

Comment: I want to use method that uses geometry like straight line is the shortest path between any two points.

Comment: @SubhashChandBhoria You're going to have some very bad time trying to prove it using only geometric methods - how are you imagining a geometric interpretation of $3^\pi$?

Comment: @SubhashChandBhoria I'm with Wojowu on this one. You can't geometrically interpret something like $3^\pi$.

Comment: that's what i'm trying

Comment: @SubhashChandBhoria Well good luck then.